# Audio Unable to Play in a Browser

Tags: android, html, audio

This audio file plays well in a Windows browser, won't work in an Android.

```
<audio id="xyz" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" src="instrumental-5.mp3">
</audio>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like following:
`<audio id="xyz" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"> <source src="instrumental-5.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> </audio>`

Comment: Tried. Works only in  Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`<audio id="xyz" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls>
<source src="http://drive.funados-radio.fr/playlist/HITS%20DU%20MOMENT/Alan%20Walker%20-%20Faded.mp3"> that is no file</audio>`
I'm check this code this code is working well in Google Chrome but doesn't work in UC browser.Some browser support and some didn't. For run this code in Google Chrome you need internet try it.